# Getting the Package name using an App name

Tags: android, package-name

I have already looked around and what I've seen was getting the `package names` or getting the `App names` and storing it in an Array List.

But what if I have an `Array list` of App names and I would like to get their package name counterpart ?

how do I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PackageManager can be used for the same.

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> l = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
String canonicalName = “”;
for (ApplicationInfo ai : l){
String n = (String)pm.getApplicationLabel(ai);
if (n.contains(name) || name.contains(n)){
        canonicalName = ai.packageName; // retrieve package name here
    }
}
```